# Перебор содержимого внутри всех div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите,как правильно реализовать перебор содержимого всех div с одинаковым классом.
Например есть следующая структура:

```
    <div class="sub-group">
    <input class="name-bool group_names" value="1" readonly="" data-optional="false">
    <div class="sub_del">✖</div>
    <div class="sub_add">+ Подгруппа</div>
    <div class="sub-group_add">+ Позиция</div>
    <div class="add_protokol_redact_add-sub-group">
        <div class="sub-group_pos">
            <input class="name-bool  pos_name_sub" readonly="" value="11" data-free="false" data-few="false" data-type="tags"
                data-optional="false">
            <div class="sub-group_add_input">
                <div class="sub-group_add_input_tags">
                    <div class="create_tags_input">
                        <div class="valTags-content">
                            <div class="valTags-main">
                                <input class="valTags tags_add_label" size="3" readonly="" value="113">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="valTags-content">
                            <div class="valTags-main">
                                <input class="valTags tags_add_label" size="3" readonly="" value="113">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="edit_priem_template_string_add plus" style="float: none; width: 20px; height: 26px; padding-left: 2px;">
                    <p class="edit_priem_template_string_add_span" style="float: none;">➕</p>
                </div>
                <div class="sub_del_pos">✖</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="add_protokol_redact_add-sub-group_content"></div>
</div>
```

Таких структур может быть N, с каждого div с классом .sub-group мне надо получить значения элементов,к примеру, с классами  .name-bool group_names, name-bool group_names и valTags tags_add_label.
Какой путь будет более менее правильный переберать через children Или find?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $subGroups = $('.sub-group'),
  reachingInputs = [];

$subGroups.each(function(idx, el) {

  var inputs = $(el).find('input');

  inputs.each(function(idx, el) {

    reachingInputs.push("{" + $(el).attr('class') + ":" + $(el).val() + "}");

  });

});


console.log(reachingInputs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-group">
  <input class="name-bool group_names" value="1" readonly="" data-optional="false">
  <div class="add_protokol_redact_add-sub-group">
    <div class="sub-group_pos">
      <input class="name-bool  pos_name_sub" readonly="" value="11" data-free="false" data-few="false" data-type="tags" data-optional="false">
      <div class="sub-group_add_input">
        <div class="sub-group_add_input_tags">
          <div class="create_tags_input">
            <div class="valTags-content">
              <div class="valTags-main">
                <input class="valTags tags_add_label" size="3" readonly="" value="113">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="valTags-content">
              <div class="valTags-main">
                <input class="valTags tags_add_label" size="3" readonly="" value="113">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="edit_priem_template_string_add plus" style="float: none; width: 20px; height: 26px; padding-left: 2px;">
          <p class="edit_priem_template_string_add_span" style="float: none;">➕</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub_del_pos">✖</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="add_protokol_redact_add-sub-group_content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Реализовать можно совершенно по-разному. Все зависит от задачи...

Например, вот так можно собрать значения в массив объектов:

```
let results = [];
for (let sg of document.querySelectorAll('.sub-group')) {
  results.push({
    nb_gn : sg.querySelector('.name-bool.group_names').value, 
    nb_pns: sg.querySelector('.name-bool.pos_name_sub').value, 
    vt_tal: sg.querySelector('.valTags.tags_add_label').value
  });
}
```